# Oracle UPDATE with two tables & CASES

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables. I'm trying to update **can_swim** field for all the records in the table based on **type** field and **feature** field which is present in different table.

**Organism table:**

```
id    type     can_swim 
----------------------
1     raven    (null)   
2     dog      (null)          
3     fish     (null)
```

**Description table:**

```
id    feature
-------------------
1      wings
2      legs
3      fins
```

The error I experienced with my query is:

```
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
        Error report -
        SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
        00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"
        *Cause:    
        *Action:
```

I'm confused as I have the SET keyword in my query.

**ORACLE Query:**

```
UPDATE organism o,  description d
SET o.can_swim = 
CASE
    WHEN o.type = 'raven' AND d.feature = 'wings' THEN 'No'
    WHEN o.type = 'dog'   AND d.feature = 'legs'  THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN o.type = 'fish'  AND d.feature = 'fins'  THEN 'Yes'
END
where o.id = d.id;
```

**Please help me resolve this.**

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE organism o
    SET o.can_swim = (SELECT CASE WHEN o.type = 'raven' AND d.feature = 'wings' THEN 'No'
                                  WHEN o.type = 'dog'   AND d.feature = 'legs'  THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN o.type = 'fish'  AND d.feature = 'fins'  THEN 'Yes'
                             END
                      FROM description d
                      WHERE o.id = d.id
                     );
```

If you don't want to update all rows, then a subquery is helpful:

```
UPDATE organism o
    SET o.can_swim = (SELECT CASE WHEN o.type = 'raven' AND d.feature = 'wings' THEN 'No'
                                  WHEN o.type = 'dog'   AND d.feature = 'legs'  THEN 'Yes'
                                  WHEN o.type = 'fish'  AND d.feature = 'fins'  THEN 'Yes'
                             END
                      FROM description d
                      WHERE o.id = d.id
                     )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM description d
                  WHERE o.id = d.id
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO ORGANISM O
USING (SELECT O.ID, CASE
                       WHEN o.type = 'raven' AND d.feature = 'wings' THEN 'No'
                       WHEN o.type = 'dog' AND d.feature = 'legs' THEN 'Yes'
                       WHEN o.type = 'fish' AND d.feature = 'fins' THEN 'Yes'
                    END AS CAN_SWIM
        FROM organism o JOIN description d ON O.ID = D.ID) SRC
ON (O.ID = SRC.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET o.can_swim = SRC.CAN_SWIM;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there - use an [*updatable join view*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11782)

```
update (
  select o.id, o.can_swim, o.type, d.feature
  from organism o
  join Description d
  on o.id = d.id
)
set can_swim =
    CASE
       WHEN type = 'raven' AND feature = 'wings' THEN 'No'
       WHEN type = 'dog'   AND feature = 'legs'  THEN 'Yes'
       WHEN type = 'fish'  AND feature = 'fins'  THEN 'Yes'
   END


select * from organism; 

        ID TYPE  CAN_SWIM           
---------- ----- -------------------
         1 raven No                 
         2 dog   Yes                
         3 fish  Yes
```

Note, that the table `description` must have a primary key on `id` (or at least an unique index).
Othervise you get an error

```
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```